# return dataset to ajax from handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my handler I am calling a stored proc and i am getting results to dataset.
When I return the dataset the ajax call goes to error function!!
I am not getting the data :(

Code in Handler

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["somename"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getassdetails", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@strassid", "111111");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            context.Response.Write(ds);
```

AJAX:

```
      $.ajax({
                    url: "Handlers/Getassdetails.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    responseType:"json",
                    success: successfunction,
                    error: errorFunction

                    });
                function successfunction(result) {
                   //some codes
                };
                function errorFunction(errResult) {
                   //some codes
                };
```

Comment: What's the error? What do you see in the response body?

Comment: `DataSet.ToString()` isn't going to give you anything useful.  You need a JSON serializer.

Comment: Agree with SLaks, and even with JSON serializer, you don't need to return the whole DataSet to client, as it's a complicated object. You need to map it to new .Net object, create them based on DataSet, and then you can use JSON serializer to return these objects.

Comment: in the responseText i am getting system.data.dataset!!

Comment: I changed the last line to 
`context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ds.ToString()));`

It goes to success function but still the result is not containing the data returned 

I was doing so long with edmx when i try to get it done without that i face these issues :/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way - use [DataSet.GetXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to write DataSet as XML string:

```
Response.Write(ds.GetXml());
```

And read data as XML in your AJAX call

```
responseType:"xml"
```

Comment: for some reasons that is not going to success function!!
But it worked when i serialized and sent data and kept responseType as json instead of xml :)

Comment: the response text is having the data !! but its going to error function

Comment: I am not getting error but the ajax call is hitting the errorfunction
The response text is containing the values in dataset though